# Rake db:migrate error 'PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "slug" does not exist'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rake

I am cloning my own repo on to my local machine that another developer has done some work on. I am trying to migrate the database and receiving this error:

```
/Users/lewisfrost/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: warning: circular argument reference - now
DEPRECATION WARNING: Support for Rails < 4.1.0 will be dropped. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/lewisfrost/frostfires/config/application.rb:8)
==  AddUploadFileToAnswer: migrating ==========================================
-- add_column(:answers, :upload_file, :string)
   -> 0.0006s
-- add_index(:answers, :slug)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "slug" does not exist
: CREATE  INDEX  "index_answers_on_slug" ON "answers"  ("slug")/Users/lewisfrost/frostfires/db/migrate/20140126204815_add_upload_file_to_answer.rb:4:in `change'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "slug" does not exist
: CREATE  INDEX  "index_answers_on_slug" ON "answers"  ("slug")
/Users/lewisfrost/frostfires/db/migrate/20140126204815_add_upload_file_to_answer.rb:4:in `change'
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "slug" does not exist
/Users/lewisfrost/frostfires/db/migrate/20140126204815_add_upload_file_to_answer.rb:4:in `change'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

SCHEMA.rb

```
  create_table "answers", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "user"
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "question_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "upload_file"
    t.string   "slug"
  end
```

Migration file

```
class AddUploadFileToAnswer < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :answers, :upload_file, :string
    add_index :answers, :slug

  end
end
```

Any advice is great

Comment: Make sure you have `slug` column in `answers` table.

Comment: @Pavan Edited my code see above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure that you don't have `slug` column in your `answers` table.

So add that using a migration:

```
rails g migration AddSlugToAnswers slug:string
```

Then, run the migration:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Schema is fine, but can you please check your database? If the `slug` column exists for the `answers` table?

Comment: If you go to your rails console and type: `Answer`, what do you see? please paste that output.

Comment: [2] pry(main)> Answer
=> Answer(no database connection)

Comment: Try: `Answer.count ` or `Answer.first`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88301/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-lewis-frost).

Answer (score 0):

That mean you don't have slug column in your table but you want to index thia column.

Check your migration files that the column exist, if not then create a migration to add slug column, then run the index.